# Adding a String[] to a mySQL database as one id/column entry

Tags: mysql, arrays, string

I am not sure based on reading the documentation if I can add multiple TEXT fields under the same Key Column for one single row.

Basically I have a String array that could be variable. For example one entry might be String[] it = new String[]{"that", "this", "thing"} and another could be String[] it = new String[]{"poo", "stuff"}.

These are going to be unique to the particular row they are associated with. I didn't see anything on the docs that would let me add the array under the various types.

I did find this answer: [Android: Sqlite saving string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053685/android-sqlite-saving-string-array/9053828#9053828)

Accepted answer seemed on track, but I'm wondering if that still applies as mySQL is today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with the answer you provided.

Otherwise you could create a new table that simulates something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE MYARRAY (
  fkRowToReference int,
  value text,
  ordinal int
)
```

With something like above each array entry would be a row in another table that references which original row it is attached to, and the ordinal would indicate its position.

```
INSERT INTO MYARRAY(1, 'that', 0);
INSERT INTO MYARRAY(1, 'this', 1);
INSERT INTO MYARRAY(1, 'thing', 2);
```