# Save ArrayList<String> to persist

Tags: java, android, string, save

My app let the user to select from a list of various apps instaled in the device, if the user selecct one or more options each selection its saved in a ArrayList as the name of the app, example:

```
ArrayList<String> appSelected = new ArrayList<>();
appSelected.add("name_of_the_app");
```

Then the array is used for another purposes.

My question is: its posible to save the array? In the way that the user does not need to re-select the apps again when the application starts, like user preferences.

Comment: Don't reuse the List for other purposes. Also Lists are serializable if that's what you mean by saving. or copy the contents to another one.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053685/android-sqlite-saving-string-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save `ArrayList<String>` in `SharedPreference`. You can not directly store a `ArrayList` in `SharedPreference`. As your list contains only `String`and `String` are `Serializable` so you can convert the list items into `String` with some joind delimiter. Then save to `SharedPreference` as a String.

To retrieve it get String from `SharedPreference` and split it with the delimiter.

**This solution will only work if your `String` don't have any comma(,)**

```
//String joinStr = StringUtils.join(stringList, ",");
String joinStr = TextUtils.join(",", stringList);
editor.putString(PREF_KEY_LIST_STRINGS, joinStr).commit();
```

And to retrieve

```
String restoredStr= prefs.getString(PREF_KEY_LIST_STRINGS, null);
List<String> restoredList = null
if(restoredStr!= null){
  restoredList = Arrays.asList(restoredStr.split(","));
}
```

This will only work for String type `ArrayList`.

`SharedPreference` is mainly used for simple data. If you are working with lots of data then consider using `Sqlite`

Comment: if I use a for cycle to join all strings with a comma (,) it work the same as StringUtils.join()? because I prefer not to use a third party libraries.

Comment: If you manually join string using loop it will work same. You can use `TextUtils.join()` in `import android.text.TextUtils` package. Check here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.Object[])