# Traverse array IN JSONArray

Tags: android, json

I'm making an app for android which makes a call to a webservice that returns a json with ARRAY as a parameter, I can go through all the settings and save them easily.

The problem is when I get the array that I returned within the JSON object.

Example of JSON:

```
[{"codigoArticulo":"0001","nombreArticulo":"CHULETAS DE CORDERO","factorVentasDefecto":"KG","precio":21.95,"factoresDeVenta":["KG","UN"]},{"codigoArticulo":"0007","nombreArticulo":"FALDETA DE CORDERO","factorVentasDefecto":"KG","precio":11.95,"factoresDeVenta":["KG","FL"]}]
```

I can save "codigoArticulo", "nombreArticulo", "factorVentasDefecto" and "precio easily, BUT i don't know how i can save "factoresDeVenta".

i have this code:

```
JSONArray resparray = new JSONArray(JSONdevuelto);

        for (int i = 0; i < resparray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject respJSON = resparray.getJSONObject(i);

            int IDArticulo = respJSON.getInt("codigoArticulo");
            String NombreArticulo =  respJSON.getString("nombreArticulo");
            String FactordeVenta =  respJSON.getString("factorVentasDefecto");
            int PrecioArticulo = respJSON.getInt("precio");
}
```

How i can save in one array the variables on "factoresDeVenta"?

I try

```
String[] Factores = respJSON.getJSONArray("factoresDeVenta");
```

but no works because are incompatible types.

I need the array to make later a Spinner

Thank you.

Comment: Calling `respJSON.getJSONArray("factoresDeVenta")` doesn't work?

Comment: But i need the values inside and i write "String[] Factores = respJSON.getJSONArray("factoresDeVenta");" and are incompatible types

Comment: JSONArray Factores = respJSON.getJSONArray("factoresDeVenta") and than iterate the JSONArray to transform it String[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`factoresDeVenta` is an JSONArray inside JSONObject so you will need to use `getJSONArray` or `optJSONArray` and use loop for getting values from JSONArray:

```
 JSONArray jArray = respJSON.optJSONArray("factoresDeVenta");
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
   String str_value=jArray.optString(i);  //<< jget value from jArray
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jArray = respJSON.getJSONArray("factoresDeVenta");
```

It would give you the array of data stored in `factoresDeVenta`, which you can again traverse to get the individual elements from that array.

Comment: within elements are varying, so I want to pick automatic mode and not the "getString ()", I can?

Comment: `jArray.get(n)` would give you the `nth` element of `jArray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can store in `ArrayList<String>`

```
ArrayList<String> arrStr = new ArrayList<String>();

JSONArray jArray = respJSON.optJSONArray("factoresDeVenta");

for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
     arrStr.add(jArray.getString(i));    
}
```

And then you can convert arraylist to string array

```
String[] Factores = arrStr.toArray(new String[arrStr.size()]);
```