# Android Studio doesn't recognize GSON Library

Tags: android, gson

I am making an app in Android Studio and I need to use `GSON` library. I have downloaded `gson-2.8.2-javadoc`. And then I followed this way

> File->New->New Module->Import .JAR/.AAR
>   Package->gson-2.8.2-javadoc->Finish

After that

> File->Project Structure->app->Dependencies->Module
>   Dependency->gson-2.8.2-javadoc->OK

but Android Studio did not recognize the `Gson`. I googled and saw the this as solution :

```
dependencies {
      implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' 
}
```

but this is not working too.

My gradle version was 4.4 and I upgraded it 4.9 , again this is not working too. Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

By the way, I tried same ways different versions of Gson Library, it did not work as well. So, what is the reason for this issue? And What is the exact solution?

Comment: post your gradle.

Comment: Solved this yet??

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have to had

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

to your application build.gradle file. Then build and it will be good

Comment: I am getting "error: package com.google.gson does not exist" error message. @adc

Comment: Did you remove the one you downloaded ?

Comment: You should have a look to this question, which is pretty much the same as yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913704/android-gradle-cannot-find-symbol-class-gson/17913798

Comment: I didn't remove. I tried to do again what you say and build was successfully but it still doesn't recognize Gson. @adc

Comment: I have seen the link you share, solutions written over there are not working @adc

Comment: can you post your build.gradle files ? @Pelin

Comment: I post it. @adc

Comment: If you deleted the one you import, clean you're project then rebuild it, it should work. You can check if the package was download after the build in your External Libraries folder. Don't forget to import Gson class where you need it and you'll be able to use it ;-) !!

Answer (score 1):

At first, Make sure you removed **`gson`** ***MODULE*** from your Project.

Read [**`How to delete a module in Android Studio ?`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592192/3395198)

`"File -> Project Structure" ->` Select **`gson`** Module and then Click **`Red Mark Negative Sign`**.

**FYI**

You should use latest version.

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.