# Adding Gson libary doesn't show up for import

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have my Android Studio project and want to add Gson to it. I added `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'` to my build.gradle so it looks like the following:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

Then re-synced. Then reloaded from disk. Finally, Invalidate Cache and Restart. Then blasted the .idea directory and reloaded. Nothing has allowed this to show up for import.

Haven't changed the root build.gradle, so it still has the right repositories. Now stuck.

It's been a while since I've done an Android project and I don't know what to try next.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51608462

Comment: @JaydeepDevda Yep, that did it. Thanks.