# How to save an arrayList of object to sqlite database

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

I have an `ArrayList` of `testobject` And I want to save it in sqlite database.

```
class testobject {
      public static String x="";
      public staticint y=0;
      public static boolean z=false;

}
```

after some search I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703330/saving-arraylists-in-sqlite-databases) And I use it.

```
 ArrayList<testobject> items=new ArrayList<testobject()>;
 items.add(new testobject());
//To insert,

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("uniqueArrays", new JSONArray(items));
String arrayList = json.toString();
// Insert the string into db.

//To Read, Read the string from db as String,

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stringreadfromsqlite);
ArrayList items = json.optJSONArray("uniqueArrays");
Log.d("","itemssize="+items.size);
```

but the problem is when I want to read my `ArrayList` from database, it gives this error message for this line **"Log.d("","itemssize="+items.size);"**:

```
java.long.NullPointException
```

actually inested of this line **"JSONObject json = new JSONObject(stringreadfromsqlite);"** I use **"JSONObject json = new JSONObject();"** is it myproblem for that?
whats wrong?
as @satur9nine said its dosn't possible to convert my ArrayList to json. so how can i save my arraylist?

Comment: What line of code gives the NPE?

Comment: The JSONObject class is not going to be able to convert your `testobject` into JSON. JSONObject and JSONArray only are able to process basic Java types like String, long, boolean, etc. Do you have a good reason why you want to store JSON in SQLite? It's not very useful since you can not search or sort the data easily, you might as well use SharedPreferences.

Comment: i update my question checkout.