# Insert ArrayList in SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, pojo

I have an ArrayList coming from an API and my POJO (Plain Old Java Object) has the required getters and setters required.

```
@SerializedName("staff")
@Expose
private List<String> staff = new ArrayList<String>();
@SerializedName("departments")
@Expose
private List<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to ad the staff and department into an **SQLite Table**.
My existing table has the rest of the strings values. But i am not able to add the **ArrayList** into the table.

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "" +
            " (" + ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY not null, " +
            //need to change product id into String or TEXT
            CLIENTS_NAME + " TEXT not null," +
            CLIENTS_ADDRESS1 + " TEXT not null," +
            CLIENTS_ADDRESS2 + " TEXT not null," +
            CLIENTS_ADDRESS3 + " TEXT not null," +
            CLIENTS_ADDRESS4 + " TEXT not null," +
            TYPE + " TEXT not null," +
            CLIENTS_CONTACT + " TEXT not null)" ;
```

How do i add the Arraylist ?
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703330/saving-arraylists-in-sqlite-databases) but its not working.
Any Links or Hints will be appreciated.

This is the insertion of the rest of the string values into the database.Note, i have still not added the **staff** into the database table yet as i dont know how to insert a Arraylist in the table.

```
 public void addProducts(Clients_POJO products) {
    //CRUD , adding Products

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.ID, products.getId());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.CLIENTS_NAME, products.getName());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.CLIENTS_ADDRESS1, products.getAddress1());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.CLIENTS_ADDRESS2, products.getAddress2());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.CLIENTS_ADDRESS3, products.getAddress3());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.CLIENTS_ADDRESS4, products.getAddress4());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.TYPE, products.getType());
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.CLIENTS_CONTACT, products.getContact());

    try {

        db.insert(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: What is your issue? Show your database insertion code.

Comment: define `it's not working`

Comment: Can we get an error message for how your SO link isn't working?

Comment: I wanna know how to Insert the staff - 
public static final List<String> CLIENTS_STAFF = new ArrayList<>();
into the table.Should i just insert it as a TEXT ? 
Like CLIENTS_CONTACT + " TEXT not null)" +
                CLIENTS_STAFF + " TEXT not null)" ;

Comment: @Neeraj - i still have not added the staff to the database. So not insertion of Arraylist . I will edit my question to add the insertion of the String values.

Comment: Don't store lists in one row. You should instead have  relationships between tables and multiple rows. Alternatively, you can use Realm, which can store lists.  https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: @cricket_007 - i have not given Realm a try yet. But it has some great functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution without converting it using GSON.**
Let the POJO value for the department be an ArrayList.

```
@SerializedName("departments")
@Expose
private List<String> departments = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To create the database we will store the column as a string in the table.

```
public static final String INPUT_DEPARTMENTS = "departments";
public static final String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "" +
            " (" + ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY not null, " +
            INPUT_DEPARTMENTS + " TEXT not null)" ;
```

Now while storing and retrieving data to and from the SQLite database.Storing ->

```
public void addProducts(Clients_POJO products) {
    //CRUD , adding Products
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.INPUT_DEPARTMENTS, String.valueOf(products.getDepartments()));
    try {

        db.insert(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
```

For retrieving data, we will convert it back to an arraylist to store the value in the POJO.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    final ProductFetchListener mListener = listener;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.GET_PRODUCTS_QUERY,null);
    final List<Clients_POJO> productsListDB = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Clients_POJO products = new Clients_POJO();
                products.setFromDatabase(true);
```

Now we convert it to an arraylist.

```
String s =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.ClientsDATABASE.INPUT_DEPARTMENTS));
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(",")));
products.setDepartments(myList);
```